# ListView get column type

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to sort a listview.

The problem is that i want it to be generic, so i want to check what is the type of the column to sort.

For some reason i cant find the solution.

somthing like :

```
if(listviewX.SubItems[ColumnToSort].GetType() == typeof(DateTime))
    compareResult = ObjectCompare.Compare(DateTime.Parse(listviewX.SubItems[ColumnToSort].Text), DateTime.Parse(listviewY.SubItems[ColumnToSort].Text));
else
    compareResult = ObjectCompare.Compare(listviewX.SubItems[ColumnToSort].Text, listviewY.SubItems[ColumnToSort].Text);
```

Comment: You can also use [ObjectListView](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html), it has more features and is better than built-in ListView.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the *type* of data present in your `ListView` columns that can be checked while filling the `ListView` then you can store their *types* with their *column indices* in some `Dictionary` like this to sort them later:

```
IDictionary<int, Type> dictColTypes = new Dictionary<int, Type>();
dictColTypes.Add(0, typeof(int)); // Column 1 type
dictColTypes.Add(1, typeof(string)); // Column 2 type
...
```

You can use `ListViewItemSorter` property for sorting as defined here with example:
[ListView.ListViewItemSorter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.listviewitemsorter%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

In above example, create a `ListViewItemComparer` class and call it like this:

```
this.listView1.ListViewItemSorter = new ListViewItemComparer(e.Column);
```

where `e.Column` is column number.